# Mounting gamepad controller for public use

Tags: gaming

I'm working on a project where we're putting an interactive PC app in a public space.  Instead of a more expensive/fragile touch-screen display I am considering using an off-the-shelf gamepad (PC/XBOX) mounted in a holder like the ones you can demo games on at WalMart or video game stores... something like this:

[image: example pic]

Anyone know where I can find a mounting system like that?  It should lock the controller in, but allow for replacing the gamepad if it gets damaged.  Bonus points for solutions that don't involve modifying (disassembling/drilling) the controller itself.  Super bonus points for adjustable height to avoid this scenario:

[image: oh the shame]

Thanks!